# automatically connect to vpn on system startup using systemd

Tags: systemd

I want to auto start vpn on system startup and reconnect ever time the network gets reconnected (after getting disconnected for any reason).

The command to connect is `protonvpn-cli connect -f`

The command to disconnect is `protonvpn-cli disconnect`

Created a file named `auto_vpn.service` in `~/.config/systemd/user` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Connect to Proton-VPN
Requires=graphical-session.target
After=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli connect -f
ExecStop=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

Then ran:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user start auto_vpn.service
systemctl --user enable auto_vpn.service
```

Now, the issue is, the service works. But when I restart the PC, the service does not start (though it is enabled). Moreover, I am not sure whether it will restart when the network gets reconnected (after getting disconnected for any reason).

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to `protonvpn-cli `

Comment: Do you have root access on the machine, and does protonvpn require to be run by a user? User services are only started by systemd when the user logs in, not when the machine boots.

Comment: Yes, I have root access (it is my desktop). No, protonvpn does not require to be run by a user. I am actually using Linux Mint 20.2 . There is a login screen and I give the login name and password. But after I login, it does not automatically connect to the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

So even though I am not familiar with the many options to be used with systemd, you can try changing the following for it to just execute and leave it as is.

Remove, `BindsTo=network.service`, since I don't think it is useful. I have run things like this without needing it.

```
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli connect -f
ExecStop=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect
```

But make sure an entry called `protonvpn-cli` is under the directory `/usr/bin`. It could be in other places depending on how you installed it.

In that case, use `whereis` to find the package.

Comment: I have tried further with your suggestion and updated the question. It is still not working.

Comment: Exactly, seeing the comments on the main question, ppl gave you good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `auto_vpn.service` in `~/.config/systemd/user` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Connect to Proton-VPN
BindsTo=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli connect -f
ExecStop=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=xsession.target
```

Now run:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user start auto_vpn.service
Run `systemctl --user enable auto_vpn.service
```

Thats it.